# Is there a specification or standard for Rust?

Tags: rust, language-specifications

Is there a specification or standard for Rust? Kind of like the ECMAScript specification for JavaScript?

I found https://github.com/rust-lang/reference, and it says:

> This document is not normative. It may include details that are specific to rustc itself, and should not be taken as a specification for the Rust language. We intend to produce such a document someday, but this is what we have for now.

Comment: I guess `language-specifications` tag is not here for _seeking_ specifications, but for _clarifying_ them. Not sure if that was the intent of creator, but that's what I'd use it for.

Comment: @Cerberus I believe that seeking clarification on whether there is some specification is border-line appropriate. I think it could've been as a GitHub issue on the project, but wouldn't close it here either.

Answer (score 5):

No, Rust is not standardized and doesn't have a complete specification as of yet. Read more about it in this great blog post by Mara Bos from Rust's library team: https://blog.m-ou.se/rust-standard/

Answer (score 2):

No, but there's not-yet-accepted RFC for that: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3355. However, it doesn't suggest a standard like C++'s, for example, read Mara's blog post for an explanation why.